# Am I missing the display of health?

Tags: red-dead-redemption

In some almost-dead situations, I am missing a display of what my actual health level is.  It's hart to tell when I need to swallow some painkillers.

Do I miss something? Is there something more "numeric" than the bloody screen?

Comment: Just adding this is how almost all first person games are doing damage indication now. Not all, but a lot. Resistance 3 is the first in a while to have an actual health bar... Well... Health circle lol

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there isn't ... the only way to tell you are about to die is the screen turning 'red-ier'.

Comment: hence the name 'red dead'..

Answer (score 1):

According to the manual, the only health indicator is the reddening screen.

Your best bet is to become familiar with the different damage levels and how dark the screen gets just before death, so that you can quickly bring up your inventory.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to find cover - your health will restore by itself over time.  I completed the game and hardly ever used any painkillers or anything else to restore health.  Just hide when in trouble!